# Почему не работает android:screenOrientation="portrait"?

Tags: java, android

В приложение нужно заблокировать возможность поворота устройства для этого я прям в манифесте прописал такую строчку

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Вот здесь

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

----> android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Я работаю на Самсунге S5 Android 5.1, почему у меня может не работать это функция?

Я тут еще почитал, что с [выходом `android 5.0`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) появилось больше возможностей настройки...

```
android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
"landscape" | "portrait" |
"reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
"sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
"userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
"sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
"user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```

Но у меня ничего не работает... Кто решал уже такую проблему?

Весь файл манифеста

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- For Google+ LogIn -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<!-- Для регистрации приложения в GCM всякий раз, когда телефон перезагружается. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android..RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.android.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.android" />

<application
    android:name=".authorization.MyFacebook"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/title"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="locked">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".gcm.GcmIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AcceptNotAccept"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomStyle" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.PopUpActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomStyle" />
    <activity android:name=".tools.TestDeleteIt" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.Welcome2" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.WebActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".authorization.AuthorizationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.WebViewAcceptReject" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.CameraActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".authorization.LogIn" />
    <activity android:name=".authorization.RegistrationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.ForgotYourPassword" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.VideoActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: а в <application, у вас есть что нить связанное с поворотами?

Comment: `android:name=".activities.Splash" ` а это имя той активити, в которой должна быть нужная ориентация?

Comment: @iFr0z Добавил весь файл манифеста. Ничего вроде там нет...

Comment: @DimXenon Ориентация нужна во всем приложении...

Comment: Вижу `android:screenOrientation="locked">`. Эта опция сохраняет ориентацию экрана, имевшую место быть при старте приложения.

Подробнее тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361338/androidscreenorientation-locked-on-old-os-versions

Comment: MainActivity.java: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: так добавьте android:screenOrientation="portrait" в <application и будет во всех активити сразу

Comment: @DimXenon да я читал и пробовал, android:screenOrientation="locked" и android:screenOrientation="portrait" , но все равно в любой момент на любом активити я могу вращать экран(( а насчет setRequestedOrientation мне нужна возможность настроить это для всего прилоения а не для каждой активити отдельно

Comment: @iFr0z я добавлял и locked  и android:screenOrientation="portrait"   но все равно в любой момент на любом активити я могу вращать экран((

Comment: Ну прям магия не иначе... а попробуйте убрать в FacebookActivity полностью строку android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" и поставьте в <application строку android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: а если android:screenOrientation="portrait|locked|nosensor"?

Comment: @iFr0z мг... убрал с фейсбука, и поставил в апп, но ниче не поменялось... Хотя если прям в джава классе прописываю setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); то работает... Я уже думал, может это телефоне проблема, но нет... Загрузил на другой девайс там тоже самое...

Comment: @Herrgott Я не могу в android:screenOrientation через "|" указывать параметры